# Construct vector from vector with conversion/scale

Tags: c++, iterator, stdvector

All

suppose I got vector with data in cm, and would like to construct another vector but in mm (or mm with a shift, or ..., so it's not quite simple).

What would be good way to accomplish such task?

I wrote some code doing iterator adapter

```
struct scaling_iterator_adaptor {
    ...
};

vector v_mm{ scaling_iterator_adaptor{v_cm.begin()}, scaling_iterator_adaptor{v_cm.end()} };
```

Is there a better way to do such task? Conceptually different way?

Comment: `reserve()`, and then a simple range iteration, `push_back`()ing the new value into the new vector. I don't see much benefit in concocting some exotic conversion iterator.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yeah, i had code which does it in two lines - reserve+for_each. Maybe it's an overcomplication...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is not essential to *construct* it with all the data contained already, you can use standard algorithms:

```
std::vector<double> v_cm{1, 3.14, 4.2};
std::vector<double> v_mm(v_cm.size());
std::transform(v_cm.cbegin(), v_cm.cend(), v_mm.begin(), [](double x){ return x * 10; });
```

You can use `std::back_inserter` if you don't want to prefill the target with zeroes.